# Error "Unknown Namespace: http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" when trying to add a custom ribbon tab in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to add a custom ribbon to an Access 2016 form as per:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-custom-ribbon-in-access-45e110b9-531c-46ed-ab3a-4e25bc9413de

The XML that I am using is a direct copy and paste from the article above.

The XML is repeated below.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com
/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabCreate" visible="false" />
      <tab id="dbCustomTab" label="A Custom Tab" visible="true">
        <group id="dbCustomGroup" label="A Custom Group">
          <control idMso="Paste" label="Built-in Paste" enabled="true"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

When I restarted Microsoft Access, I get the following error:

```
Error found in Custom UI XML of "D:\CLIR\Research\AccessToPostgreSQL\NWBAccess.accdb":

Line 2
Column 26
Error Code 0x80004005
Unknown Namespace: http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customUI
Element: customUI
```

I have found that changing this to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui` works.

Is there an updated version of this schema that should be used for Access 2016 and later?

Comment: Not that I know of. Review https://www.accessribbon.de/en/

Comment: There's a linebreak in that URL. Afaik that's relevant and you should remove it (linebreaks matter in quoted sections of XML)

Answer (score 0):

sounds unusual but I had the same issue.
I overwrote the spec to "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customUI"
and all is well